# Redireccionar si se cumple un if en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, botón, onclick

Es un login, al pulsar el boton, valida los datos y redirecciona a la página principal.

```
var usuarios=["hola"];
var contraseñas=["1234"];

function validar()
{
    var usuarioR=document.getElementById("usuario").value; 
    var contraseña1=document.getElementById("contra").value;

    for(var i=0; i<usuarios.length; i++) 
    {
        if(usuarioR == usuarios[i])
        {
            for(var j=0; j<contraseñas.length; j++) 
            {
                if(contraseña1 == contraseñas[j])
                {
                    location.href = "PáginaPrincipal.html";
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Contraseña incorrecta.\nPor favor, confirma tu contraseña.");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("¡Aún no te has registrado!");
        }
    }
}
```

Si valida los datos, pero no quiere redireccionarme, al mandar un alert en vez del location.href si me lo muestra.

Comment: Es una muy mala idea tener los datos de ingreso en Javascript, se pueden ver fácilmente al revisar el código fuente. Por otra parte, no deberías recorrer las contraseñas, sino usar el mismo índice del usuario.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente? La validación de contraseñas nunca se hace en el cliente por lo que te comenta @Triby. Por otra parte, evita el uso de palabras/variables/urls con acento o caracteres especiales, esto te puede traer problemas.

Answer (score 2):

Fuera del hecho de que como mencionan los comentarios de la publicación guardar información de usuario en *javascript* no es recomendable, el uso que haces de `location.href` es el correcto pues bien si intentas llamar un `file2.html` desde un `file1.html` y ambos se encuentran en el mismo directorio solo bastara con colocar el nombre de `file2.html` dentro de `location.href`:

```
location.href = "file2.html"  //también funciona:  "./file2.html"
```

Si el archivo que intentas acceder esta en un subdirectorio:

```
location.href = "subdir1/file2.html"  //también funciona "/subdir1/file2.html"
```

Si el archivo que intentas acceder esta en un directorio superior:

```
location.href = "../file2.html"
```

Es probable que te hayas equivocado con el nombre del archivo o que este se encuentre en un directorio distinto del archivo donde lo estas llamando.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con `window.location`

```
window.location.href = 'PáginaPrincipal.html';
```

También verificá que el nombre del archivo *PáginaPrincipal.html*, no tenga tilde o acento.

Comment: `window` es global, le va a dar el mismo resultado.